# click on tag a in button is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the html code as below:

```
<button type="button" class="btn d-btn btnActor" style="background: #9cc447;" rel="tooltips" title="Militant" data-x = '1' data-y = '4' id='btn-matrice1'>

            <p style="color:#fdff36; font-size:10px;text-decoration:underline;line-height:0px;padding-right:35px; padding-bottom:6px;"><a style="color:#fdff36;" class='list'>Liste</a></p>
            <p style='color:#ffffff; font-size:10px; line-height:0px;'>Militant</p>
            <p style="color:#ffffff; font-size:10px; line-height:0px;">&nbsp;</p>
            <p style="font-size:10px; line-height:0px; padding-left:35px;" class="count" data-count="1" mytag="1"></p>
</button>
```

And the jquery code:

```
 $('button').on('click', 'a.list',function(e) {   
            alert(1); 
  });
```

When I click it is not working. Anyone help me  to fix it please..

Comment: There was `'` missing after `a.list`. Assuming it as a typo

Comment: It works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/LLBzr/

Comment: Markup is not valid as per html5 specification.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use this:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: $('button').on('click', 'a.list', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('document').on('click', 'a.list',function(e) {   
                alert(1); 
      }); 
});
```

Comment: Check the question again i guess someone has edited it , "'" quote is added now..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("button").click(function(){
    alert("button");
  }); 
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$ ("button"). on ('click', function() {   
            alert(1); 
  }); 
});
```

Use `ready()` to make a function available after the document is loaded

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is because the target object (your `<button>`) has to exist in the [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) for the `jQuery.on()` function to work properly. This is according to the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

From jQuery doc linked above:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page.

You are likely placing your `jQuery` at the top of the page, before the button 'exists' in the DOM.

To fix, either place the `jQuery` below the button (such as in a `<script>` tag at the bottom of your page), or - *preferably* - use `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('button').on('click', 'a.list', function (e) {
        alert(1);
    });
});
```